# Python checking list for a 2D board

Tags: python, list

Say I have a list like so:

```
board = 
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0,], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0,], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0,], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0,], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0,]
```

that represents spaces on a 2D board.
If player one goes, it will change to 1.
If player two goes, it will change to 2.

Win conditions are: if a row or column is completely filled, or diagonally.

Here are my functions for horizontal or vertical winners:

```
def horizontal_winner(board, boxes):
    '''
    function will find if the horizontal win conditions apply
    given 2 inputs. the board, a list and the number of boxes
    - board - the 2D board of the game
    - boxes - number of boxes per side
    ''' 
    for i in range(boxes):
        player_1 = 0
        player_2 = 0
        for j in range(boxes):
            if board[i][j] == 1:# first iteration - [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
                player_1 += 1
                print("p1: " + str(player_1))
            elif board[i][j] == 2:# first iteration - [2, 0, 0, 0, 0]
                player_2 += 1
                print("p2: " + str(player_2))
        if player_1 == boxes:
            return True
        elif player_2 == boxes:
            return False


def vertical_winner(board, boxes):
    '''
    function will find if the vertical win conditions apply
    given 2 inputs. the board, a list and the number of boxes per side
    - board - the 2D board of the game
    - boxes - number of boxes per side
    '''
    for i in range(boxes):
        player_1 = 0
        player_2 = 0 
        for j in range(boxes):
            if board[j][i] == 1:# first iteration - [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
                player_1 += 1
            elif board[j][i] == 2:# first iteration - [2, 0, 0, 0, 0]
                player_2 += 1
        if player_1 == boxes:
            return True
        elif player_2 == boxes:
            return False
```

How would I check diagonally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, recognize that there are only 2 diagonals.  And the coordinates of each box on them is either (i, i) or (boxes-i-1, i) for some i in range(boxes).  That should help you figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this, using `all()`:

starting from `i=0` to `i=len(board)-1`, the diagonal elements can be fetched using `board[i][i]`:

```
In [116]: board=[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0,], 
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0,], 
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0,], 
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0,], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1,]]

In [117]: all(board[i][i]==board[0][0] for  i in range(len(board)))
Out[117]: True

In [119]: [board[i][i] for  i in range(len(board))]  #value of diagonal elements
Out[119]: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

# another example:

In [120]: board=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0,], 
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0,], 
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0,], 
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0,], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1,]]

In [121]: [board[i][i] for  i in range(len(board))]
Out[121]: [0, 1, 1, 1, 1]

In [122]: all(board[i][i]==board[0][0] for  i in range(len(board)))
Out[122]: False
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to consider four cases separately. I will explain with example

Consecutive 1's in a single Row

```
>>> board1 =[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0,],
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1,],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0,],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0,],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0,]]
>>> any(map(all,board1))
True
```

Consecutive 1's in a single Column

```
>>> board2 =[[0, 1, 0, 0, 0,],
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0,],
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0,],
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0,],
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0,]]
>>> any(map(all,zip(*board2)))
True
```

Consecutive 1's in forward diagonal

```
>>> board3 =[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0,],
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0,],
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0,],
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0,],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1,]]
>>> all(list(islice(chain(*board3),0,None,len(board4)+1)))
True
```

Consecutive 1's in reverse diagonal

```
>>> board4 =[[0, 0, 0, 0, 1,],
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0,],
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0,],
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0,],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0,]]
>>> all(list(islice(chain(*reversed(board4)),0,None,len(board4)+1)))
True
```

so to summarize

```
from itertools import chain, isclice
any(any(map(all,board)),
    any(map(all,zip(*board))),
    all(list(islice(chain(*board),0,None,len(board4)+1))),
    all(list(islice(chain(*reversed(board)),0,None,len(board4)+1))))
```